# Uncheck all dynamically created checkboxes: Angular2

Tags: angular

I have dynamically created checkboxes in my UI and I want to uncheck them when a link is clicked. I'm approaching it in the following way:

```
....
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="checkBox">
....
```

their are more than one checkbox inputs dynamically created with a for loop and I'm assigning the same boolean object 'checkBox' to the [checked] attribute. But this approach works when I have a single checkbox, it doesn't work with multiple dynamically created checkboxes.

How can I fix this? Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ngFor?

Comment: @SherinBinu, yes I'm using *ngFor to generate the inputs

Comment: I've tried. But it works for me. Is your problem the checkbox not getting created or it's not responding to the Boolean variable?

Comment: @SherinBinu, thanks for confirming but can you provide a fiddle to show how its working for you?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to use jsfiddle for Angular 2. But here is my code.

Comment: Since I cant format them in a comment, I will add it in an answer

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Show us some more code, what do you mean by *it doesn't work with multiple dynamically created checkboxes*? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

HTML code is

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toggleCheckBox()">Toggle CheckBox</button>
<input *ngFor="let array of arrays" type="checkbox" [checked]="checkBox">
```

TypeScript code is

```
checkBox = true;
arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

toggleCheckBox() {
  this.checkBox = !this.checkBox;
}
```

As long as your array is right and multiple checkboxes are created, I dont find any reason why its not working

Comment: Try this:might helps: <input *ngFor="let array of arrays" type="checkbox" [(checked)]="checkBox">